# Going from Observable to Enumerable/Value without Blocking

Tags: f#, system.reactive

I'm having some blocking problems.  I am trying to go from push to pull.  i.e. I would like to access my data here which in this case is an array after it has been processed through my Observable.

```ml
type HistoryBar = 
    {Open: decimal; High: decimal; Low: decimal; Close: decimal; Time: DateTime; Volume: int; RequestId: int; Index: int; Total: int}

let transformBar =
    client.HistoricalData
    |> Observable.map(fun args ->
        {
            Open = args.Open
            High = args.High
            Low =  args.Low
            Close = args.Close
            Time = args.Date
            Volume = args.Volume
            RequestId = args.RequestId
            Index = args.RecordNumber
            Total = args.RecordTotal
       }
    )

let groupByRequest (obs:IObservable<HistoryBar>) = 
    let bars = obs.GroupByUntil((fun x -> x.RequestId), (fun x -> x.Where(fun y -> y.Index = y.Total - 1)))
    bars.SelectMany(fun (x:IGroupedObservable<int, HistoryBar>) -> x.ToArray())

let obs = transformBar |> groupByRequest

client.RequestHistoricalData(1, sym, DateTime.Now, TimeSpan.FromDays(10.0), BarSize.OneDay, HistoricalDataType.Midpoint, 0)
```

If I subscribe to obs, than as soon as I make a call to `client.RequestHistoricalData` everything works fine.  What I would like to do is convert obs to the underlying type which in this case is `HistoryBar []`.  I have tried using `wait`, `ToEnumberable` with no luck.  What is the proper approach here to pull out my last created piece of data?

Edit, adding contrived C# example code to show how the library normally works.  What I am really trying to understand here is how one can go from observable to a standard list or array.  What I am not certain of is if I required a mutable structure in order to do so.  If I had to guess I would say no.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
...
client.HistoricalData += client_HistoricalData;
client.RequestHistoricalData(1, sym, DateTime.Today, TimeSpan.FromDays(10), BarSize.OneDay, HistoricalDataType.Midpoint, 0);
....
}

static void client_HistoricalData(object sender, HistoricalDataEventArgs e)
{

Console.WriteLine("Open: {0}, High: {1}, Low: {2}, Close: {3}, Date: {4}, RecordId: {5}, RecordIndex: {6}", e.Open, e.High, e.Low, e.Close, e.Date, e.RequestId, e.RecordNumber);
}
```

Comment: What does `client.RequestHistoricalData` do? Please elucidate. Calling `ToArray` inside `SelectMany` causes blocking eager evaluation of the whole sequence.

Comment: Added more details. `client.RequestHistoricalData` will make a call to perform a data fetch which in term will call the event handler associated with `client.HistoricalData`

Comment: The contrived code in C# remains, well, contrived.

Comment: Not sure why `ToEnumerable` doesn't work here?  You'll *have* to block, because the `IEnumerator<T>` can't yield anything until something is observed to yield back to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question doesn't make very clear how the data is loaded in the first place (whether it is lazy / time-variant etc.) so I'll just assume that it's a time-bound stream of values.

From your code it seems like you want to find the last value in the stream when it completes. The `Last` method gives you the last value in the stream that was pushed when it completes - this is however synchronous and blocks till the stream completes. The non-blocking version, `LastAsync` returns an Observable which produces a value when the source completes.

```
let from0To4 = 
    Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1)).Take(5)

let lastValue =
    from0To4.LastAsync()

let disposable =
    lastValue |> Observable.subscribe(log)
```

To convert the Observable into a list without blocking in parts, you can use the `Buffer` methods. To buffer all values until the Observable completes, use `ToList`.

```
let fullBuffer =
    from0To4.ToList()

let disposable =
    fullBuffer |> Observable.subscribe(fun ls -> printfn "Buffer(%d): %A" ls.Count ls)
```

Output:

> Buffer(5): seq [0L; 1L; 2L; 3L; ...]

Comment: `Observable.ToList()` would be more appropriate here than calling `Buffer(Observable.Never())`, noting that they work in exactly the same way essentially. `Observable.ToList()` is non-blocking and returns a single notification (the list) when the underlying completes.

Comment: Not sure how this relates.  I am going from a .NET event handler `client.HistoricalData` that is triggered after the call to `client.RequestHistoricalData`

Comment: @davewolfs Is your goal to convert all instances of the event into a list?